# Error while calling C DLL function from Python

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to execute my Python Code that must call a C function, which execute some calculation and save the value in a pointer that must be accessible from Python code. I'd like to do that because i'm constructing a DLL and i want to validate the algebra inside the DLL function, therefore i'd like to use a python code to validate the DLL. 
The Python Code

```
from ctypes import *


if __name__ == '__main__':

    mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("./dll_simples.dll")
    funcao = mydll.simuser
    funcao.argtypes = c_double,c_double,POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double)



    a = 0
    b = 0
    input_1 = (c_double * 1)()
    input_1[0] = 5
    output_1  = (c_double * 1)()
    funcao(a,b,input_1,output_1)
```

and my DLL

```
__declspec(dllexport) void simuser(double t, double delt, double* in, double* out)
{



out[0] = 2 * in[0];



}
```

after executing this code, i have the error

```
funcao(a,b,input_1,output_1)

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000018
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: have you tried `funcao(a,b,byref(input_1),byref(output_1))`

Comment: Is python a requirement for some reason?  Why not test from C and save all the DLL hassles.  If you needed exceptions and such then use C++ or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

So, you want to pass an array to a function that expects a pointer. For that case, *ctypes.cast* is required:

So, instead of:

```py
funcao(a, b, input_1, output_1)
```

use:

```py
funcao(a, b, cast(input_1, POINTER(c_double)), cast(output_1, POINTER(c_double)))
```

Looking at the existing *C* code, it only uses one value for the 2 pointers, case in which you won't be needing arrays at all (but I doubt that's the intent because then the input value shouldn't be a pointer):

```py
# ...

input_1 = c_double(5)
output_1 = c_double(0)

funcao(a, b, byref(input_1), byref(output_1))
```

A working example: [[SO]: Pointer from Python (ctypes) to C to save function output (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753828/pointer-from-python-ctypes-to-c-to-save-function-output/54756627#54756627).

Comment: i tried this approach in the simplified code with only 1 argument

Comment: I really don;t understand what you said. What exactly did you try? Did it work?

Comment: i'm sorry. The comment was incomplete unintentionally. I'd like to say that i've tried your approach but it didn't work. So i've simplified the code in order to have only 1 pointer array using your approach ('cast' function). But i'm still struggling to make this piece of code work well. I'll post here the solution when i find it.

Comment: i must use array because in the future it'll be an array that will be sent to a C dll which will calculate some stuff and save in another array (output_1).

Comment: i'm sorry, your answer is correct. The error is inside my C code. When i have Py_Initialize(); inside the DLL nothing works. This DLL must initialize a Python interpreter that works fine when i call DLL from C code, but when is Python code calling the DLL it cracks with the error "OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000025".

Comment: I have edited a question to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937552/c-dll-crack-when-called-from-python.

Comment: This is very important information that belongs in the question. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details. Why do you need both *CTypes* and *Py\_Initialize*? It sounds like a design problem. Also try ***pydll*** instead of *cdll*. Also I thonk this answers the question as it is right now, so you could accept it, then focus on the other question.

Comment: I'm using a comercial software which simulates physical things, i can interact with the simulation to feedback information(Control theory), it can be done in this software with a DLL, that i'm using with python interpreter because my feedback function are in python. I'd like to have a code in order to debug my DLL with python functions, so i thought that call my DLL from a python script would allow me to test the DLL(with python interpreter and my python functions inside it). But i'm open to better ideas. Tkss

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. Thank you!! Obs: I've just accepted your answer, sorry i didn't know that i had this privilege.